webpack [Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined]
I recently started learning webpack and ran into the following problem. I have a configuration file webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./public/js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/js"),
    globalObject: "this",
    filename: "vendor.js",
  },
  watch: true,
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {},
};

I'm using express.js as the server. I have a main file index.js and two files where I divided the logic into modules: tabs.js
function tabs() {
  const tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent");
  const tabheader__item = document.querySelectorAll(".tabheader__item");
  const tabheader__items = document.querySelector(".tabheader__items");
  function hideTabContent() {
    tabcontent.forEach((tab) => {
      tab.style.display = "none";
    });
    tabheader__item.forEach((item) =>
      item.classList.remove("tabheader__item_active")
    );
  }
  hideTabContent();
  function showTabContent(index = 0) {
    tabcontent[index].style.display = "block";
    tabheader__item[index].classList.add("tabheader__item_active");
  }
  showTabContent();

  tabheader__items.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("tabheader__item")) {
      tabheader__item.forEach((elem, index) => {
        if (e.target === elem) {
          hideTabContent();
          showTabContent(index);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

module.exports = tabs;

and modal.js:
function modal() {
  const data_modal = document.querySelectorAll("[data-modal]");
  const modalWindow = document.querySelector(".modal");
  const data_close = document.querySelector("[data-close]");

  const showModal = () => {
    modalWindow.style.display = "block";
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  };
  const closeModal = () => {
    modalWindow.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
  };

  data_modal.forEach((modalItem) => {
    modalItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
      showModal();
    });
  });
  data_close.addEventListener("click", () => {
    closeModal();
  });

  document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      closeModal();
    }
  });
}

module.exports = modal;

I'm trying to require these two functions in the main index.js file. The console shows no errors. Here is the index.js file
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const tabs = require("./modules/tabs");
  const modal = require("./modules/modal");

  tabs();
  modal();

});

This is what the console outputs
npx webpack
asset vendor.js 3.78 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main) 1 related asset
./public/js/index.js 183 bytes [built] [code generated]
./public/js/modules/tabs.js 980 bytes [built] [code generated]
./public/js/modules/modal.js 802 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.91.0 compiled successfully in 44 ms


Nothing works for me when the page loads. the functions do not work, the modal window does not open. And the console in the browser gives an error:
index.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index.js:2:16

Photo file locations


index.js, is this error from the browser, as you should be loading vendor.js,  and putting your source in ./public/js is not normal either.

could you please explain in more detail?

Could you answer my question, I know I never put a question mark in the question, but there was a question there. :)   Otherwise I'll be wasting mine & your time, if the error is not from the browser..

yes I will try to answer. of course

...multiple potential points of confusion here: it is not entirely clear, reading this question, whether or not you understand the difference between server-side node.js code and client-side browser code and why you can't mix the two. It also isn't clear whether or not you are trying to do that. Secondly, browsers do not have a require function, and webpack cannot magically make them do so. Calling require in a script tag like that isn't going to work. Typically with webpack you bundle all your js code into a single file (sharding the bundle is a more advanced topic).

I was able to fix the error. You're right, I still have a vague idea of ​​how the server works with the client. I just had to take the output from the public folder. This is how express.js works.   code now                                                                                         const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
mode: "development",
entry: "./public/js/index.js",
output: {
path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist"),
globalObject: "this",
filename: "vendor.js",
},
watch: true,
devtool: "source-map",
module: {},
};
